# Is there a way to get a pastable link from Google Maps Directions Service?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When we use maps.google.com, there's a way to 'Send' the current directions searched via email. One could also copy-paste a unique URL - even shorten it.

Is there a way to get this through the JavaScript API (v3)?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the directions and store it in the database - after that you can generate a link to recall the route, and shorten it with the [Google URL Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started)

Comment: i don't really care if its a short or long url. also, there would be too many combinations of destinations to store

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't do this, because if you have start and end locations in order to get directions, it's quite easy to construct a url yourself:

`http://maps.google.com/?q=from:A to:B` (encoded if necessary)

If you want to use *your* map to show the route, then you will need to implement your own system of querystring parameters and handle those in your map page.

Comment: you mean the saddr= and daddr= ?
i'd also often have intermediate destinations. I find the URL that Google Maps webpage generates has some other params too - would that not affect anything in some cases?

Comment: Slight inaccuracy now corrected. You need colons. `from:Eastbourne UK to:London UK to:Birmingham UK`